# Compiled GNU/Nano: How to add to system editors list

Tags: nano, alternatives

I have compiled GNU/Nano editor myself and I wish to add it to the system editors list.

```
which nano
```

Tells me the following location:

> ```
> /usr/local/bin/nano
> ```

So it should be something like:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/bin/nano 1
```

But I need to put pieces together. Could you help me with understanding the manual please?

> **COMMANDS**
>
> ```
> --install link name path priority [--slave link name path]...
> ```
>
> Add a group of alternatives to the system.  `link` is the generic name for the master link,  `name`  is  the name of its symlink in the alternatives directory, and `path` is the alternative being introduced for the master link.  The arguments after  `--slave` are  the  generic name, symlink name in the alternatives directory and the alternative path for a slave link.  Zero or more `--slave` options, each followed  by  three arguments,  may  be  specified.  Note that the master alternative must exist or the call will fail. However if a slave alternative  doesn't  exist,  the  corresponding slave  alternative  link will simply not be installed (a warning will still be displayed). If some real file is  installed  where  an  alternative  link  has  to  be installed, it is kept unless `--force` is used.
>
> If  the  alternative  name  specified  exists  already in the alternatives system's records, the information supplied will be added as a new set  of  alternatives  for the  group.  Otherwise, a new group, set to automatic mode, will be added with this information.  If the group is in automatic mode, and the newly added  alternatives' priority  is  higher than any other installed alternatives for this group, the symlinks will be updated to point to the newly added alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out what the package does in its [`postinst`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/nano/blob/master/debian/nano.postinst):

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /bin/nano 40 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/editor.1.gz editor.1.gz \
  /usr/share/man/man1/nano.1.gz
```

This installs `/bin/nano` as an alternative for `/usr/bin/editor` (the alternative named `editor`, so `/etc/alternatives/editor`), with priority 40, and associates the `nano` manpage as an alternative for the `editor` manpage. That way, selecting `nano` as the configured alternative automatically sets up the manpage to match.

When this is run, if an `editor` alternative already exists, `nano` will be added, and if the alternative is in automatic mode, selected if it has the highest priority; if not, the alternative will be created in automatic mode, `nano` will be added and selected.

So you probably want something like

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/bin/nano 100
```

(assuming you want to automatically select `nano`; the highest priority I see for an editor in Debian is 70, so 100 will win).